# DELL Precision 7530 BIOS update problems on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dell, bios, acpi

there is an annoying problem due to the updating of my DELL Precision 7530 bios (from 1.10.1 to 1.11.1 or 1.12.1) with Ubuntu 18.04 on board: after upgrade, some functions key (Wifi, Brightness Up/Down, Microphone On/Off and probability others) no longer work.

Looking in the syslog I see some errors correlated to ACPI Bios component:

```
    atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x88 on 
    isa0060/serio0).
    atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e008 <keycode>' to make it known.
    ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.NHDA], 
    AE_NOT_FOUND (20181213/psargs-330)
    ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \NEVT, AE_NOT_FOUND 
    (20181213/psparse-531)
    ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed 
    \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181213/psparse-531)
```

This forced me to reinstall the bios version 1.10.1.
How is it possible to solve the problem? Is it a bug related to the BIOS or is it necessary to resolve into linux kernel?

Thanks in advance.